# np.dot of two 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to using numpy so sorry if this sounds obvious, I did try to search through stackoverflow before I post this though..

I have two "list of lists" numpy arrays of length n (n = 3 in the example below)

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]])
```

I want to get a 1d array with the dot product of the lists at each corresponding index, i.e.

```
[(1*2 + 2*2), (3*3 + 4*3), (5*4 + 6*4)]
[6, 21, 44]
```

how should I go about doing it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
np.sum(a*b,axis=1)
```

Comment: i know it must be straightforward but i have no idea it should be done in np.sum instead of np.dot. thanks!!

Comment: I mean, `np.diag(a @ b.T)` works as well, but is less apparent what you want

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` method in the other answer is the most straight forward method:

```
In [19]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
    ...: b = np.array([[2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]])
In [20]: a*b
Out[20]: 
array([[ 2,  4],
       [ 9, 12],
       [20, 24]])
In [21]: _.sum(1)
Out[21]: array([ 6, 21, 44])
```

With `dot` we have think a bit outside the box.  `einsum` is easiest way of specifying a `dot` like action with less-than-obvious dimension combinations:

```
In [22]: np.einsum('ij,ij->i',a,b)
Out[22]: array([ 6, 21, 44])
```

Note that the `i` dimension is carried through.  `dot` does `ij,jk->ik`, which would require extracting the diagonal (throwing away extra terms).  In `matmul/@` terms, the `i` dimension is a 'batch' one, that doesn't actually participate in the sum-of-products.  To use that:

```
In [23]: a[:,None,:]@b[:,:,None]
Out[23]: 
array([[[ 6]],

       [[21]],

       [[44]]])
```

and then remove the extra size 1 dimensions:

```
In [24]: _.squeeze()
Out[24]: array([ 6, 21, 44])
```

In `einsum` terms this is `i1j,ij1->i11`