# sum product of 2d with 3d numpy arrays plus a scalar computation

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

just asked a basic [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059860/np-dot-of-two-2d-arrays) earlier on dot product of two 2d arrays with hopes that I can then figure out how to expand the logic to the following question where one matrix is actually in 3d and then further multiplied by a 1d scalar vector, with no success... sorry for the back-to-back questions, numpy looks much more complicated that I thought..

I have the following 3 arrays

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
b = np.array([[[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]])
c = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

I'd like to do the following computation. I am just going to type out the formula directly as I am not sure how to properly describe it in words (if someone can enlighten me on this as well I would be interested to know!)...

```
[[(1*1 + 0*2 + 1*3)/1, (1*1 + 1*2 + 0*3)/2, (0*1, 1*2, 1*3)/3],
 [(1*3 + 1*4 + 1*5)/1, (0*3 + 1*4 + 0*5)/2, (0*3, 0*4, 1*5)/3]]

>>> [[4, 1.5, 1.67], [12, 2, 1.67]]
```

it probably have to do with how to use the axis arg but I can't figure out quite yet... thanks much again!!

Comment: Writing out the formula for the multiplication and summation part is quite often done using the einstein notation. This also quite directly leads to a possible implementation `np.einsum("ij,ixj->ix",a,b)/c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer: `np.sum((a[:,None,:] * b), axis=2) / c`

Process step by step visually:

[image]

**Additional comments**

1. `a[:,None,:]` inserts an extra dimension in the middle of size 1. `a.shape` is `(2, 3)` and `a[:,None,:]` is `(2, 1, 3)`. `a[None,:,:]` and `[a[:,:,None]` does the same, you can check it with a `shape` parameter.
2. One of approaches of understanding this problem is visual. All the pictures demonstrate how three dimensions corresponds to `axis=0`, `axis=1`, `axis=2`. So if you had an array of `shape = (2, 1, 3)`, its visualisation would be a cuboid of height = 2, width = 1 and lenght = 3. For example, you can see **visually** how `a[:,:,None]` and `b` are broadcasted into a new array `a[:,:,None] * b`.
3. There's also a **symbolic** (formal) way to see it. Only arrays of balanced shapes could be broadcasted. So arrays of shapes `(2, 3)` and `(2, 1, 3)` can't be broadcasted unlikely to arrays of shapes `(2, 3, 3)` and `(2, 1, 3)`. **But,** arrays of shapes `(4, 3)` and `(3,)` can be broadcasted. I mean, there are [mathematical rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy) which defines whether arrays are broadcastable.

Comment: thanks for the answer and even more importantly for my understanding the visualisation. i can't quite wrap my head around how `a[:,None,:]` worked to turn it into (2, 1, 3)... is it possible for you to give me more insights? of coz I went ahead and tried `a[None,:,:]` and `a[:,:,None]` but again i couldn't quite understand why the outputs are the way they are ... what surprises me is that `a[None,:,:]` is `a` itself..

Comment: @mathfux : what did you use to make these plots ?

Comment: @tgrandje it's my own tool called [`numpyviz`](https://github.com/loijord/numpyviz). Check out `sputnik5` in both sputnik_scripts and sputnik_gallery directories and you'll find the script I used to create this visualisation.

Comment: @minovsky No, `a[None,:,:]` is not the same as `a`: `array([[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]])` ≠ `array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])`. the main difference is that they have a different shape.

Comment: @minovsky Check my update of an answer. You might also like to see this [excellent article](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d) that underlies my ideas.

Comment: Also, last two pictures were not correct, fixed it.

Comment: thanks a lot, @mathfux. i will need some time to digest all of these but i should be on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

That may not be what you were looking for exactly (as it reshapes the numpy array using a list, which is not very efficient), but it seems to work :

```
d = np.array([[row]*3 for row in a]) #reshape np.array to 3d
print((d*b).sum(axis=2)/c)
```